# MySQL server will not start after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, mysql, database

I had a MySQL server on my machine, and then I got the helpful free Windows 10 upgrade.

I updated to Windows 10 and then I tried to start the server again
after a reboot and I cannot get it to work.
I am using the command in Command Prompt:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --console
```

I get an error that this is not a recognised command. I navigated to that folder and no "mysqld" file exists, but this command worked before to start the server.

What should I do to get the server up again without uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Any messages when you try to start it? Does event viewer show any crash information?

Comment: Did you choose to keep everything?  Have you tried to simply install MySQL again?

Comment: I get the message "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --console is not a recignised command"